# jQuery/Javascript, populate a Google Maps 'zoom' variable dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script:

```
        var c = container,
        f = c.parents('.point_form'),
        p = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        mapzoom = parent.cpm_map_zoom.value;
    m = new google.maps.Map(c[0], {
    zoom: mapzoom,
        center: p,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId['ROADMAP'],
```

The 'mapzoon' variable is correctly populated with a an integer.

However, 'zoom: mapzoom,' does not pickup the value.

I am a total jQuery noob with little-to-no idea what I am doing. All I need to do is set 'zoom:' to the value in 'mapzoom.'

First one with the correct answer is my hero for life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your `mapzoom` variable does not contain an integer. Try this after you set the variable:

```
console.log( typeof mapzoom );
```

It logs `'string'`, doesn't it? You need to convert it to a number, which you can easily do like this:

```
mapzoom = +parent.cpm_map_zoom.value;
```

Comment: Wow. So simple. You,sir, are truly a hero. Thank you!